# MyActivity keeps crashing (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I know there's a bunch of questions regarding this, but my question is specific to my code.

Below is what I have

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    {

    @Override
    public boolean supportRequestWindowFeature ( int featureId);

    }
}
```

I've added this part, because I didnt want the action bar and top bar to be visible on the app,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But now, for some reason the syntax of the below is conflicting with my app's startup,

```
@Override
public boolean supportRequestWindowFeature ( int featureId);
```

I'm really lost right now. I dont understand why Android Studio is telling me that it's expecting a colon ";" and also don't understand why it's telling me annotations aren't allowed on this line,

```
public boolean supportRequestWindowFeature ( int featureId);
```

Here's a snapshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaPoK.png

Thanks in advance to anyone who bothers to help a rookie out! :)

Comment: if the app crashes... post your logcat: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: supportRequestwindowfeature;(); --> supportRequestwindowfeature() { }

Answer (score 1):

remove the "{" before your `@Override` and the ";" before the "(" in

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(..){

} 

@Override
public booleansupportRequestWidownFeature(int .... ){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your putting up your function oddly.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}



@Override
public boolean supportRequestWindowFeature ( int featureId)
{

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is no action bar...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Immersive mode...

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        mainScreen.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.public class LoginActivity extends Activity;

2.in AndoridManifest.XML file,add this:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

and remove `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`